# Gradle: Change artifact names only on publishing to local

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to append the suffix `-LOCAL` to my artifact version only when I publish to `mavenLocal()` using the plugin `maven-publish` so that when I want to add it to my dependencies of my other project,
I can add the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("my.group", "my-jar", "1.0.0-LOCAL")
}
```

The solution that I tried is by concatenating the string at the `publishing

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            artifacts {
                artifact(tasks["sourcesJar"]) {
                    builtBy(tasks["remapSourcesJar"])
                    version += "LOCAL"
                }

                artifact(tasks["javadocJar"]) {
                    version += "LOCAL"
                }
                artifact(tasks["remapJar"]) {
                    version += "LOCAL"
                }
            }
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven(url = "some url") { name = "E" }
        }
    }
}
```

But, the change is not dynamic, this will change the version name when I publish
to other repository too (probably, I have not tried it yet). I only want to change
this only when publishing locally.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have 2 publishing artefacts and then conditional publish .. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_customization.html

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenLocal(MavenPublication) {
            version += "-LOCAL"
            from components.java
        }
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("$buildDir/repos/releases")
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("$buildDir/repos/snaps")
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) {
    onlyIf {
        publication == publishing.publications.maven
    }
}
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenLocal) {
    onlyIf {
        publication == publishing.publications.mavenLocal
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked when running `publishToLocalMaven` task but not when running `publish` task ie the unmodified artifacts are uploaded to local too. Is there a way to fix this or prevent uploading to local when running `publish` task?

Comment: changed the condition to inclusive rather than exclusive - should work now

Comment: Should set the classifier instead, version + LOCAL doesn’t mean anything

Comment: sorry for the late ping, setting classifiers is really helpful indeed since i wont affect my jar SemVer